# Unhandled exception. System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: When trying to increase value

Tags: c#

Here is the code snippet, where I am trying to find out the duplicate number in an array.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var map = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            int[] nums = new int[]{ 1,3,4,2,2};

            for(int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            {
                map[nums[i]]+=1;

                if(map[nums[i]] > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(map[nums[i]]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you're initialising an ***empty*** dictionary. then trying to access an element from it. which must fail, because an empty dictionary has no elements. you must _set_ some values in your dictionary first.

Comment: `map[nums[i]]+=1;` <-- this is a problem. your  `map[]` does not contain key `nums[i]`

Answer (score 2):

the answer for this is is that you need to use other features of the dictionary

```
if (map.ContainsKey(key))
{
    int current = map[key];
    map[key] = current + 1;
}
else
    map.Add(key, 1);
```

This will get you where you are going